# My UITableView always comes back to top

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, scroll

When I make my UITableView scroll down and release it, it automatically comes back to the first cell. What should I do ? I created it only programatically :

```
table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 900) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[table setScrollEnabled:YES];
[table setScrollsToTop:NO];
[table setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 900)];
```

Please help !

Comment: Do you mean it scrolls to the first cell, or it appears at the top of the view hierarchy? I think more code or a better description is required.

Comment: the tags has scrolling and uiscrollview, so i think he means it scrolls to the first cell.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry. In fact I want to create a table view looking like the musics list of the iPhone, but when I make it scroll down, it doesn't keep scrolling down but always comes back to the first cell.

Comment: FYI, `setScrollsToTop` has nothing to do with this behaviour: it allows the table view to scroll to the top when the user taps the iPhone status bar or the navigation bar of your controllers.

Comment: And you absolutely don't need to `setContentSize` on your table view. This is the task of the delegate method `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Right, I removed it. Still doesn't work. (but thanks for information)

Comment: Have you anywhere put the method `scrollRectToVisible` ?? It may also cause to scroll to the position passed to it.

Comment: How should I use this function ?

Comment: I am having the same problem too. The UITableView scrolls to the top when you scroll down. Only by REALLY scrolling down hard at the bottom of the UITableView will it go to the bottom or lower cells.

Answer (score 1):

remove the code line

```
[table setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 900)];
```

from your code, it is happening because of this. thank you.

Comment: use code formatting `` and put all your code in between those so rader can get proper idea about what you like to say easily